# Visual Studio plugin for collapsing C++ codes

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I want a Visual Studio plugin to collapse C++ code in visual. For example, I want to collapse the statements in a `if` block (as shown below). I know Visual Studio has the "outline" menu, but it doesn't seem to work well for me because it sometimes collapses macro defines and other things.

Does anyone know of a tool that can help me?
[image: collapsing example]

Comment: I sometimes did something like `#if 1 /* block to collapse */ #endif`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to enable this feature :

Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C/C++ -> Formatting -> check everything in "outlining"

Then, reopen the source file to reload outlining.

(PS. This works at least in Visual Studio 2008.)

Comment: and visual studio 2010, while in VS2013 it moved to Tools -> Options -> Text Editor -> C/C++ -> Formatting ->View ->check everything in "outlining"

Answer (score 0):

I have been using Visual Assist X plugin for Visual Studio with great success. It can do what you are looking for and then a lot more.

Unfortunately this is not free software, but this is one of those developer tools that improve your productivity a lot and really worth paying for.

Comment: Visual Studio is also not a free software and its licenses costs much more than VA X.

Comment: You are preaching to the choir - I cannot agree more here. To me VA X is the only thing that makes Visual Studio bearable.